# Function not calling from NSTimer selector in swift (work in simulator but not in device)

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I want to check that how many time my application can stay in background. So I have managed it using this code

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
   print("entered in background")
   let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60 * 5, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   timer.fire()
}
```

my update function

```
func update(){ 
   print("func call")
}
```

All this code work in simulator but whenever I run my project in device it didn't call this function.
This function work also when application in foreground to check proper timer work or not also function call.
I am using swift 2.0.
Possibly apply all solution but no success.

**EDIT:**
Also apply this code

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector(update()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

but it call function only first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your App enters background, there will be no guarantee that the timer is going to fire. You might get some time before your tasks are halted by iOS but sometimes you get none, for example when the device is locked.
If you want to run things in background, you need to take a look at [Background Mode Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring your method like so:

```
func update(sender: NSTimer?) -> Void { 
    print("func call")
}
```

and make sure you call it like this (notice the semi-colon:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    print("entered in background")
    let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(60 * 5, target: self, selector: "update:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   timer.fire()
}
```

Comment: already tried but no success....it simply print "entered in background" but no longer print function statements

Comment: oh, I just noticed that you're calling this when the app goes into background... why would you do that? try in the appDidEnterForeground and see if it works

Comment: this method not present. applicationWillEnterForeground is present.   but i want to check how many time application can stay in background....so i have used this

Comment: Why don't you store a time variable when app goes to background, and use the time variable to see how much time passed when app enters foreground